# How can I change my extension method in C#

Tags: c#

I started to use this extension that I found on the web:

```
public static class NewLabelExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
        {
            return LabelFor(html, expression, new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
        }
        public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
        {
            var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
            var htmlFieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
            var labelText = metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName ?? htmlFieldName.Split('.').Last();
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(labelText))
            {
                return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
            }

            var tag = new TagBuilder("label");
            tag.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
            tag.Attributes.Add("for", html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(htmlFieldName));
            tag.SetInnerText(labelText);
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
        }
    }
```

I use it like this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Login.RememberMe, new { @class = "adm" })
```

The result is like this:

```
<label class="adm" for="Login_RememberMe">Remember me?</label>
```

However I would like to style this label. I don't really understand the code that I am using. Can anyone suggest a change to the code above that would make the LabelFor method generate?

```
<label class="adm" id="Login_RememberMe" for="Login_RememberMe">Remember me?</label>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why you want to create a label for itself? id and for attributes should not be same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to add the below line :

```
 tag.Attributes.Add("id", html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(htmlFieldName));
```

code:

```
   public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
        var htmlFieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        var labelText = metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName ?? htmlFieldName.Split('.').Last();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(labelText))
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }

        var tag = new TagBuilder("label");
        tag.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        tag.Attributes.Add("id", html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(htmlFieldName));
        tag.Attributes.Add("for", html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(htmlFieldName));
        tag.SetInnerText(labelText);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }
```